# ASP.NET Core 3.1 does not call PostConfigure on the class implementing IPostConfigureOptions<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

In my ASP.NET Core 3.1 application, I want to do some settings AT THE END since they are dependent on some other services being registered in the Startup.cs only. Can someone help me to understand why my class implementing the `IPostConfigureOptions<T>` is never invoked by .NET Core?

I have an `Options` class like this:

```
public class MyTestOptions
{
    public string TestTest { get; set; }
}
```

This is used in the `Startup.cs`'s `ConfigureServices` method as usual.

```
services.Configure<MyTestOptions>(o => { o.TestTest = "Test Test Test"; });
```

I need to change some settings "at the end". So, I implement `IPostConfigureOptions<T>` interface. The implementation class looks like this. (PostConfigure method not shown in the snippet below).

```
public class MyTestPostConfigure : IPostConfigureOptions<MyTestOptions>
```

This is then registered in the `Startup.cs`'s `ConfigureServices` method as shown below.

```
services.ConfigureOptions<MyTestPostConfigure>();
```

I tried to register PostConfig class in different way too.

```
services.AddSingleton<IPostConfigureOptions<MyTestOptions>, MyTestPostConfigure>();
```

However, in any case the `PostConfigure` is not called.
Am I missing something?
**

1. Why the PostConfigure is never executed?
2. Isn't it true that all IPostConfigureOptions get executed automatically during startup? Or is there any case when .NET Core chooses not to run it until it's actually required?**

Comment: Off the top of my head, I thought you are supposed to have a `services.PostConfigure<T>(...);` line in there?

Comment: @DavidG: That too does not work.. I tried ervices.PostConfigure<T> too..

Comment: Show where you try and _consume_ `MyTestOptions`. Is that in a controller, using DI, for example? Do you see the `Test Test Test` value set?

Comment: @KirkLarkin: Is it that `IPostConfigureOptions<TOptions>` will not be invoked if `TOptions` is not used anywhere as a dependency? ... I understand that practically we will create it because it's required somewhere.. But still a theoretical question to understand if .NET Core skips `IPostConfigureOptions<TOptions>` if `TOptions` is not used anywhere..

Comment: Yup, that's correct. It runs both the `Configure` and `PostConfigure` stuff on-demand. If you don't resolve `IOptions<MyTestOptions>` etc from the DI container, those configuration callbacks aren't going to run.

Comment: Thanks @KirkLarkin. In my case, I am using `IOptions<MyTestOptions>` as a dependency in some other class already. I see that the constructor of the `MyTestPostConfigure` class gets called but `PostConfigure` method is never called. I don't seen `Test Test Test` value set on the property either.. Unable to understand what's going wrong..

Comment: @KirkLarkin: Thanks for your inputs and time. The problem is solved and I have added details in the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to @KirkLarkin for the inputs he gave in the comments to my question.

The `PostConfigure` method on the `MyTestPostConfigure` class was not called because I was not accessing properties of `MyTestOptions` anywhere in my application.

I had injected `IOptions<MyTestOptions>` as a dependency in one of my classes and that's why constructor of the `MyTestPostConfigure` was called. However, since I was not using anything from the `MyTestOptions` class, .NET Core was not calling `PostConfigure` method.

As soon as accessed the `TestTest` property of the `MyTestOptions` class, I see that .NET Core executed both the `Configure` and `PostConfigure`.

In short, **the execution of the `Configure<TOptions>` and `IPostConfigureOptions<TOptions>` is on-demand and it's delayed until you "actually use" the `TOptions` properties; merely injecting it as a dependency does not make .NET Core DI  call the `Configure` and `PostConfigure` methods.**

(I don't know on-demand configuration is documented anywhere or I missed this basic thing altogether.. )

Comment: I ran into a different issue with IConfigureOptions but this post led to the fix. When injecting the options into a class, make sure to inject IOptions<YourClass> and not just YourClass. Otherwise, the Configure methods don't get called. Thanks!